# HTML broken Format with hidden divs

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to put a web form together for work that after a selection from a drop down is made the correct questions with be revealed up to be filled out. I have the form working, however, my formatting is all out of whack. What I would like to do is keep everything in a nice straight line when displaying the questions without any gaps with the hidden text

When you Run the program you can see a space between the drop down and the questions 49 and 50 (if it is possible I would want to eliminate that gap), I also tried to hide a whole `div` If you were to select "Red" it will then separate question into 3 parts.

I have tried to cut the code down as much as I could. Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/72j0vzuc/47/)

```
<!-- Main Content Area -->
<div class="main">
  <div class="row">
        <form> <!-- Form tag is only used to allow the Clear button at the bottom to clear the data entry area. -->
            <!-- Begin left side data entry -->
            <div class="cell" style="vertical-align: top; padding-top: 10px;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell">Color:</div>
                    <div class="cell">
                        <select id="Color" onChange="myWorkLog();myWorkLogs();store_value('Color',this.value);showQuest(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);"> 
                            <option label=" "></option>
                            <option >Blue</option>
                            <option >Red</option>
                            <option >Green</option>
                            <option >Orange</option>
                            <option >Yellow</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>  
                </div>
                <!--  Blue Questions -->
                    <div class="row">
                         <div class="cell" id="Q1" style="display:none" >Question 1 Question 6 Question </div>
                         <div class="cell"><input type="text" id="A1" style="display:none" onChange="myWorkLog();myWorkLogs();" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                         <div class="cell" id="Q2" style="display:none">Question 2</div>
                         <div class="cell"><input type="text" id="A2" style="display:none" onChange="myWorkLog();myWorkLogs();" /></div>
                    </div>
                <!--  Reds Questions -->
                <div class="cell" id="Reds" style="display:none">
                    <div class="row">
                         <div class="cell" >Question 7 may be longer than the rest</div>
                         <div class="cell"><input type="text" id="Q7" onChange="myWorkLog();myWorkLogs();" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                         <div class="cell" >Question 8</div>
                         <div class="cell"><input type="text" id="Q8" onChange="myWorkLog();myWorkLogs();" /></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <!--  Green Questions -->
                    <div class="row">
                         <div class="cell" id="Q3" style="display:none">Question 3</div>
                         <div class="cell"><input type="text" id="A3" style="display:none" onChange="myWorkLog();myWorkLogs();" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                         <div class="cell"id="Q4" style="display:none">Question 4</div>
                         <div class="cell"><input type="text" id="A4" style="display:none" onChange="myWorkLog();myWorkLogs();" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <!--  Orange Questions -->
                    <div class="row">
                         <div class="cell" id="Q5" style="display:none">Question 5</div>
                         <div class="cell"><input type="text" id="A5" style="display:none" onChange="myWorkLog();myWorkLogs();" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                         <div class="cell" id="Q6" style="display:none">Question 6</div>
                         <div class="cell"><input type="text" id="A6" style="display:none" onChange="myWorkLog();myWorkLogs();" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <!--  Yellow Questions -->
                    <div class="row">
                         <div class="cell" id="Q9" style="display:none">Question 5</div>
                         <div class="cell"><input type="text" id="A9" style="display:none" onChange="myWorkLog();myWorkLogs();" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                         <div class="cell" id="Q10" style="display:none">Question 6</div>
                         <div class="cell"><input type="text" id="A10" style="display:none" onChange="myWorkLog();myWorkLogs();" /></div>
                    </div>
                <!--  Always needed Questions -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell">Question 49</div>
                    <div class="cell"><input type="text" id="Q49" onChange="myWorkLog();myWorkLogs();" /></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell">Question 50</div>
                    <div class="cell"><input type="text" id="Q50" onChange="myWorkLog();myWorkLogs();" /></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="cell" style="text-align: center;"><input type="reset" value="Clear" /></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript to un-hide

```
document.getElementById('Color').addEventListener('change', function() {

    var style = this.value == 'Blue' ? 'block' : 'none'
    document.getElementById('Q1').style.display = style;
    document.getElementById('Q2').style.display = style;
    document.getElementById('A1').style.display = style;
    document.getElementById('A2').style.display = style;


    var style = this.value == 'Red' ? 'block' : 'none'
        document.getElementById('Reds').style.display = style;

    var style = this.value == 'Green' ? 'block' : 'none'
    document.getElementById('Q3').style.display = style;
    document.getElementById('Q4').style.display = style;
    document.getElementById('A3').style.display = style;
    document.getElementById('A4').style.display = style;

    var style = this.value == 'Orange' ? 'block' : 'none'
    document.getElementById('Q5').style.display = style;
    document.getElementById('Q6').style.display = style;
    document.getElementById('A5').style.display = style;
    document.getElementById('A6').style.display = style;

    var style = this.value == 'Yellow' ? 'block' : 'none'
    document.getElementById('Q9').style.display = style;
    document.getElementById('Q10').style.display = style;
    document.getElementById('A9').style.display = style;
    document.getElementById('A10').style.display = style;
});
```

If this is something that is impossible with the way I am trying to build this, I welcome any suggestions that I can research to get to my final product. Thank you in advance.

Comment: all your divs are present there and its taking the height, just make sure to display all other row divs which you dont need to show,

Comment: Your code looks ungly. Too much repeat. You can write it better. Also your html on change attribute is too big. Write it in JavaScript instead

Comment: I have no desire to look at the problem closely. Please refactor your code before  : onChange="onlyOneFunction();"  .  function setVisible(id, vis) { document.getElementById('Q3').style.display = vis:'block' : 'none';}     .use let and const instead of var.  ...

Comment: no need for:  class="cell"    -->   .row > div {}

Comment: Thank you all for looking at my sloppy code, this is one of my first attempts at writing anything. I will try and implement your suggestions and edit the code

Comment: Perhaps you can you render your html with js:    ele.innerHTML = '...';  Too much similar html code.     https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself        Sorry for my harsh words

Comment: It's important to keep coding. it will be better step by step.  Don't wory.

Comment: No Harsh words were spoken, I knew it was ugly and there had to be a more efficient way of writing it. Being I was thrown into this, I did it the easiest way i could find.

Comment: Perhaps you can use a simple library like this:  https://preactjs.com/.   A good IDE can help you a lot:  https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/

Comment: I think your problem is that you're using "display:none;" when you really want "visibility:hidden;".